# Dynamic event attachment not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var smartActionsId = ['smartActions1','smartActions5','smartActions10'];

for (var i in smartActionsId) {
     console.log("smartActionsId ="+smartActionsId[i]);
    $('#' + smartActionsId[i] + ' select').change(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var disableValue;
        var ruleIndex = smartActionsId[i].substr(11);
        console.log("smartActionsId ="+smartActionsId[i]+" i ="+i);
        if (value === '0') {
            disableValue = true;
            onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
        }
        else if (value === '1') {
            disableValue = false;
            onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
        }
    });
}
```

I'm creating change event dynamically for a multiple switch slider items using the above JavaScript code. But problem I'm facing is, when I click on any switch 'i' value gets replaced with the last value i.e. in smartActionsId I have 3 elements, which ever switch I change it effects for last switch (smartActions10).

Could you please help me resolving this issue?

Comment: Prepare a fiddle please..Atlease share html

Comment: There's no need for a loop, since all of the callbacks are the same except for the `this` they reference (and your `ruleIndex` var). Try `var ruleIndex = $(this).attr('id').substr(11);`

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky `this` doesn't reference `#smartActionX` but the `select` underneath it.

Comment: @jack yes I saw it after I commented :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to attach event listeners inside a `for` loop because the variable that tracks the index is used by each loop cycle. If you do that, the `i` variable will always equal the length of the array minus 1. Use `Array.prototype.forEach()` instead to prevent that.

```
var smartActionsId = ['smartActions1','smartActions5','smartActions10'];

smartActionsId.forEach(function (identifier, index) {
  console.log("smartActionsId ="+identifier);
  $('#' + smartActionsId[index] + ' select').change(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var disableValue;
    var ruleIndex = smartActionsId[index].substr(11);
    console.log("smartActionsId ="+smartActionsId[index]+" index ="+index);
    if (value === '0') {
      disableValue = true;
      onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
    }
    else if (value === '1') {
      disableValue = false;
      onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
    }
  });
});
```

**Please Note**: IE8 and down does NOT support `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

Comment: `Array.forEach()` is not supported in IE8 and below.

Comment: Thanks primostyle.. Its working fine now

Answer (score 2):

Other answers here fixed your problem, but I think you can refactor your code a little and make it much more understandable.

First, I don't like IDs. in your scenario, you have multiple ids which needs to be treated the same. Why not use one mighty class?

Also, ruleIndex calculated from element's ID? smells rotten.
If it tells you something about the element, it should be in an attribute or a data-* attribute.

The first bit of code *fixes* the markup by adding `ruleIndex` as data attribute and adding a `.smart-actionable` class. (Maybe you can even move this part to the server-side, to provide yourself with easier markup for JS).

Now, this makes the event handling quite simple.

```
var smartActionsId = ['smartActions1','smartActions5','smartActions10'];

for (var i in smartActionsId) {
    $('#' + smartActionsId[i])
      .data('ruleIndex', smartActionsId[i].substr(11))
      .addClass('smart-actionable');
}

$('.smart-actionable').on('change', 'select', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var disableValue = (value === '0');
    onRuleToggle(disableValue, $(this).data('ruleIndex'));
});
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You cant use `for...in` in this case. Please try the code below:

```
var smartActionsId = ['smartActions1', 'smartActions5', 'smartActions10'];

for (var i = 0; i < smartActionsId.length; i++) {
    console.log("smartActionsId =" + smartActionsId[i]);
    $('#' + smartActionsId[i] + ' select').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var disableValue;
        var ruleIndex = smartActionsId[i].substr(11);
        console.log("smartActionsId =" + smartActionsId[i] + " i =" + i);
        if (value === '0') {
            disableValue = true;
            onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
        } else if (value === '1') {
            disableValue = false;
            onRuleToggle(disableValue, ruleIndex)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This still exhibits the problem of the value of `i` not being closed over.

Answer (score 1):

I've always use names like `smartActions_1`. If you can use it, then in your `.change` function you can use

```
// if 'smartActionsId' is global variable
// and if you need to get position in 'smartActionsId' array
var numInArray = $.inArray( this.parentNode.id, smartActionsId );
// this - your select DOM object
var ruleIndex = parseInt( this.parentNode.id.split( "_" )[ 1 ] );
```

And remember that `this` in `.change` function its `select` which have no `id` and you must use `this.parentNode` or `$( this ).parent()` to get it's holder (I think its `div` or somethink like that).

@Jack in comments is right: select may not be a direct child. Then you can use this code:

```
var parent = $( this ).closest( "[id^=smartActions]" );
var numInArray = $.inArray( parent.attr( "id" ), smartActionsId );
var ruleIndex = parseInt( parent.attr( "id" ).split( "_" )[ 1 ] );
```

Comment: Due to the selector, it may not by `parentNode` you need to look at.

Comment: @Jack I think you not right, can see there http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/uVSkJ/

Comment: The selector is `#zyz select`, so a `select` below an `#xyz` but not necessarily a direct descendent (child).

Comment: @Jack, now I understand about what you say.